# How to implement Auto-Hide Scrollbar in SWT Text Component

Tags: swt, scrollbar

I have a SWT Text component, for which I set `SWT.MULTI`, `SWT.V_SCROLL` and `SWT.H_SCROLL` to show the scrollbar when required.
I found that even content is smaller than the text component then also scrollbar are visible in disable state.

Is there is any way through which I can auto hide the scrollbar? Like java Swing has JScrollPane.horizontal_scrollbar_as_needed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That works on all cases:

```
Text text = new Text(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);

Listener scrollBarListener = new Listener () {
  @Override
  public void handleEvent(Event event) {
    Text t = (Text)event.widget;
    Rectangle r1 = t.getClientArea();
    Rectangle r2 = t.computeTrim(r1.x, r1.y, r1.width, r1.height);
    Point p = t.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT,  SWT.DEFAULT,  true);
    t.getHorizontalBar().setVisible(r2.width <= p.x);
    t.getVerticalBar().setVisible(r2.height <= p.y);
    if (event.type == SWT.Modify) {
      t.getParent().layout(true);
      t.showSelection();
    }
  }
};
text.addListener(SWT.Resize, scrollBarListener);
text.addListener(SWT.Modify, scrollBarListener);
```

Comment: excellent, thanks so much! This finally worked for me, it is the only way to get rid of horizontal sliders in RAP.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `StyledText` instead of `Text`. `StyledText` has method `setAlwaysShowScrollBars` which can be set to `false`.

Comment: Works, but sorrowly `StyledText` seems to not support `setEnabled(boolean b)` correct. See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=4745

Comment: @de-jcup The bug has been fixed 2019 so your comment is no longer valid.

Comment: Great to hear the problem exists no longer - thank you @howlger

Answer (score 6):

@Plamen: great solution thanks. I had the same problem but for a multiline-text with style SWT.WRAP without a horizontal scrollbar.

I had to change a few things in order to make this work properly:

```
Text text = new Text(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.WRAP | SWT.V_SCROLL);

Listener scrollBarListener = new Listener (){
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        Text t = (Text)event.widget;
        Rectangle r1 = t.getClientArea();
        // use r1.x as wHint instead of SWT.DEFAULT
        Rectangle r2 = t.computeTrim(r1.x, r1.y, r1.width, r1.height); 
        Point p = t.computeSize(r1.x,  SWT.DEFAULT,  true); 
        t.getVerticalBar().setVisible(r2.height <= p.y);
        if (event.type == SWT.Modify){
           t.getParent().layout(true);
        t.showSelection();
    }
}};
text.addListener(SWT.Resize, scrollBarListener);
text.addListener(SWT.Modify, scrollBarListener);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=180027) you can't hide vertical scroll bar, it's OS (Windows) specific L&F. You can get rid of horizontal bar by using `SWT.WRAP` without `SWT.H_SCROLL`.