# SWT - How to tell that widget/composite has a scrollbar or object at certain coordinates is the scrollbar

Tags: java, widget, swt

Considering one Shell that holds a scrollable List.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/Demonstratesscrollbars.htm

How could it be determined that a point in the widget represents the scrollbar?
Is it possible to do so? using style and other composite properties to retrieve the scrollbar?

What is the design? The scrollable holds the list or scrollbar is part of the list?

```
Table table = new Table(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.CHECK | SWT.RESIZE | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);

 List list = new List(shell, SWT.V_SCROLL);
```

I should check for **SWT.V_SCROLL** and **SWT.H_SCROLL** on the composite? but still, need to retrieve the scrollbar object and check that coordinates are inside the scrollbar?

Comment: Why do you want to know? This would be difficult, for example on macOS scroll bars are not shown at all most of the time.

Comment: If you are interested in auto-hiding the scrollbars, then have look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547428/how-to-implement-auto-hide-scrollbar-in-swt-text-component to get some ideas.

Comment: @greg-449, this is not for macOS

Comment: @Shashwat not for auto-hiding, but might help. first I have to figure out how to find and instantiate the scrollbar when I have the composite and then check the point be inside the scrollbar

Comment: Controls with scroll bars extend `Scrollable`. That has `getHorizontalBar()` and `getVerticalBar()` methods to access the `ScrollBar` widget. `ScrollBar` has `getSize` but there isn't anything to access its exact position.

Comment: @greg-449, in order to check that control is scrollable I can use .GetStyle() == SWT.V_SCROLL for vertical?

Comment: It is probably better to check the value of `getVerticalBar()` is not null.